# Alexa interaction with ESP32 chip

Tags: arduino, alexa-skills-kit, arduino-ide, interaction, esp32

I'm developing an IOT project on an ESP32. The ESP32 will need to interact on voice commands from the Alexa Echo. What's the best way to approach this? I found a library (named: FauxmoESP). Whit this library I can interact between the ESP32 and de Echo. My question her is. Is this a legitimate solution for bringing this ESP32 to market? If not. What's the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found it already, Espressif has official SDK for Voice assistant.

https://github.com/espressif/esp-va-sdk

It has examples for Alexa, Google Voice Assistant and Google Dialogflow.

The SDK is updated frequently.

Why not give it a try?